# Гендерно-нейтральные и небинарные местоимения

Tags: местоимения, обращение

В английском языке есть трансгендерные местоимения - (s)he и ze, they в единственном числе. Существуют ли аналоги в русском языке?

Как еще проявляется гендерная нейтрализация языка?

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99713/discussion-on-question-by-pashapash-----).

Answer (score 9):

Насколько понимаю, вопрос о лексических средствах выражения этой самой "гендерной неопределённости" в русском. Если одним словом: "Нет". Ничего похожего в русском я не наблюдаю.

Говорить об английском здесь много не хочется, да и не настолько я им владею, чтобы менторствовать. Но уж коли вопрос поставлен так, что нужно какое-то сравнение с английским, то попробую развить мысль.

Давайте посмотрим, зачем это в английском и почему это так решается.
В английском языке у существительных (и имён вообще, включая местоимения) нет категории грамматического рода. Единственный способ обозначить пол грамматическими средствами — he и she со всеми их производными.  Далее в ход идут уже лексические средства — male/female (тоже в весьма ограниченном числе), профессионализмы и разговорные суррогаты (tom-cat/molly-cat). Такая убийственная грамматическая простота — палка о двух концах: в частности, he и she всегда обозначают лицо (много реже — живое существо или персонажа) соответствующего пола, при неопределённости приходится как-то выкручиваться.

В русском ничего этого просто не надо. Врач — он. Или она. Когда неизвестно — согласование по мужскому роду вполне приемлемо. "Некто" — он. Хотя может быть и женщиной. Ну и т. д. Русская грамматика просто не ставит перед говорящим таких задач поиска точного соответствия грамматического рода фактическому. А потому — и задач выражения гендерной неопределённости.

На самый крайний случай есть универсальное слово "это" ("то, что"). Которое вопреки всем другим заменителям имеет средний род. Правда, применение его к одушевлённым объектам несколько затруднительно, но это уже другой вопрос, для одушевлённых объектов таким заменителем выступает "(тот,) кто" — вполне себе мужского рода.

Вообще проблема если и имеет место, то только для переводчиков.
Тут недавно столкнулся с обратным переводом с английского на украинский.
Зеленский сказал что-то о неизвестной на тот момент кандидатуре нового Генпрокурора. Который — **он**, ибо прокурор — м. р.

На английский перевели типа "he or she has to do something...". Ну и понеслось. В официальном тексте появилось "он или она" уже на украинском и на русском. Что породило массу конспирологических версий о том, что на этот пост рассматривалась кандидатура некой дамы.

Это я к тому, насколько по-разному решают вопрос половой неопределённости русский и английский языки — при содействии неумелых переводчиков.

Comment: *Вообще проблема, если и имеет место, то только для переводчиков* — вроде перед "если" лишняя запятая, нет? Has to sth — не очень понял...

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой *перед "если" лишняя запятая* - да, спасибо... *Has to sth — не очень понял* - "has to do somthing". Этого не поняли? Ну я полностью написал. так понятнее?

Comment: 'Has to do something' понимаю, без 'do' просто фигня выходит какая-то.

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой ну не фигня, положим... обычное сокращение. Но я полностью написал.

Comment: *...обычное сокращение* — нет, что касается самого сокращения, то я не против совсем. :) 'Do' только, считаю, опускать нельзя.

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой я именно про "do". Но мне совершенно не хочется обсуждать здесь английские словарные условности.

Answer (score 2):

Про [**ze**](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/ze) я сейчас услышал первый раз в жизни, но судя по описанию:

> The genderqueer community are the primary proponents of ze. One refers
>   to a person with ze and hir or zir typically (a) when their gender is
>   unknown, and one wishes to avoid assuming their gender, or **(b) when
>   they are neither male nor female in gender**, making he and she (and
>   also either/or terms like s/he or (s)he) *inappropriate and potentially
>   hurtful*.

в русском интернете для варианта b) сейчас модно использовать **оно**. Правда, это не только *potentially*, а вполне себе умышленно *hurtful*.

**Добавлено**:

Здесь достаточно подробно и много по теме вопроса, но только по-английски (заголовок я зачем-то перевел):
["Гендерная нейтральность в языках с грамматической категорией рода"](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gender_neutrality_in_languages_with_grammatical_gender).

В том числе есть раздел про **Russian**.

Но, вообще-то, из вашего вопроса непонятно, как вы сами это явление понимаете. А потому трудно обсуждать, как оно проявляется и проявляется ли.

**Добавлено №2**

В качестве иллюстрации к вышеприведенной статье: такие вот заголовки порой появляются на новостных сайтах:

ria.ru:

> "В Саратове задержали подозреваемого в изнасиловании врача"

gazeta.ru:

> "В Саратове задержан подозреваемый в изнасиловании спешившей на вызов врача"

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99362/discussion-on-answer-by-tum-----).

Comment: Отличная статья. Да,  у нас нет местоимений,  но есть существительные.

Answer (score 1):

В русском популярные местоимения для небинарных личностей:

- они
- оно

Как таковые аналоги "neopronouns" мне не встречались, но Михаил Эпштейн предложил переиспользовать "оне" - устаревшее множественное женское местоимение.

Источники по теме:

- https://knife.media/gender-neutral/
- https://www.wonderzine.com/wonderzine/life/life/251493-them-they-theirs
- https://makeout.space/2017/02/27/genderno-neytralnyy-yazyk.html
- https://ru.pronouns.page/pronouns

Answer (score 0):

Поражённый канцеляритом мозг чиновника, которому надо соблюдать "гендерную нейтральность", запросто выкручивается из ситуации, даже если русский язык определяет для каждого слова конкретный род. Например:

> Согласно имеющимся данным, подозреваемый(-ая) покинул(-а) помещение в 17:35. Он(а) имел(а) при себе 3 (прописью: три) портсигара отечественных и куртку замшевую.

Если *где-либо* введут закон об обязательном использовании гендерно-нейтральных местоимений, а в случае русского языка и гендерно-нейтральных остальных частей речи, то придётся просто ставить больше скобочек, чтобы никого невзначай не оскорбить.

Универсальных местоимений, к сожалению, в русский язык не завезли. Всем беспокоящимся о концентрации скобочек на квадратный сантиметр экрана рекомендую сообщать всем собеседникам свои предпочитаемые местоимения, например, в пользовательских профилях или в подписях. Также в ваших силах добавить кавайности в язык, предложив собеседникам использовать местоимения вроде "мя" и "тя".

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99712/discussion-on-answer-by-athari-----).

Comment: Обновил ответ в соответствии с [рекомендацией модератора](https://rus.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/497/%d0%9c%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80-%d1%83%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%bb-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d1%82/498?noredirect=1#comment1016_498) на Мете.